# Error: cannot add .mxml file to project

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flash-builder, cairngorm, parsley

I have a project .swc made with maven. the build is successful.
If I add the project to Flashbuilder, i get no errors.
But if i add a .mxml file with flashbuilder, so its generated from flashbuilder.

Then i get This error:

> **1172: Definition mx.core:DeferredInstanceFromClass**

could not be found.

if i add .as file then there is no problem.

does anyone have an idea or solution to this problem..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what adding an MXML file to a Flash Builder project has to do with a SWC built from Maven.

However, errors such as the one you state often crop up when there is a SDK version mismatch between the library project and main project.  So, be sure that your SWC is being compiled with the same version of the SDK that your main project uses.

Comment: don't think this is the reason. but who can i check witch version maven uses to compile?

Comment: @Mathijsm I assume who ever set up Maven build for you should be able to tell which SDK the SWC uses.

Comment: ok seems that they are the same.  It seems i fixed the problem by copying form an other generated maven project in the  .actionScriptProperties  the  <libraryPath > block  to the new  .actionScriptProperties file and  it works and in the Poms are same dependencies

Comment: Be sure to post that as a formal answer if that is how you solved your problem.  ;)